# .dll application name

Tags: .net, dll

Writing a .NET DLL how do I find `Application.ProductName`?

**EDIT:**
Obviously, importing `Windows.Forms` could solve the problem, but my DLL have nothing to do with Windows Forms.

Comment: You need to find a reason that makes technical sense to justify avoiding putting a reference to Windows.Forms.  You aversion to putting in that reference makes no sense to me, since it's part of the framework, which you need to run your DLL at all anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Application` class just needs a reference to `System.Window.Forms`. So the simpler way is to add that reference in your *.dll and use the property.

However if you are not allowed to reference the Windows Forms library you can somewhat replicate the functionality in a custom class of yours and read the [AssemblyProductAttribute](http://AssemblyProductAttribute) from the assembly you consider to be your application. For a console application you would consider the assembly returned from `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` to be your application.

Comment: hmm, what should be "worst" to import: Windows.Forms or System.Reflection?

Comment: Taking in consideration that `Application.ProductName` uses `System.Reflection` the only choice to make is: Should I reference Windows Forms and get cleaner and tested code or just add more code to maintain?

Answer (score 2):

Tested in C#.  Should be fine in VB at least.. not sure about c++

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName
```

Comment: heh. You impose me to import Windows.Forms in a .DLL